# js object to clojurescript vector/map

Tags: javascript, interop, clojurescript

Through a Jsonp call I fetch some (json) data from a remote api, response:

```
#js [#js {:id 1501} #js {:id 1502}]
```

How do I turn them into a clojurescript vector with maps inside?

i.e.

```
[ {:id 1501} {:id 1502} ]
```

Answer (score 3):

`js->clj` will convert it to a clojurescript vector.  Add `:keywordize-keys true` and you'll get the maps inside.

Like this:

```
(def json #js [#js {:id 1501} #js {:id 1502}])
(js->clj json :keywordize-keys true)
```

Comment: Be sure not to use defonce here instead of def because the {:keywordize-keys true} option won't work.